# How to create a testArray in JUnit

Tags: java, arrays, junit

I'm trying to test my program (TicTacToe) in several JUnit testcases. The methods I want to test are in the class "Board" (inside the same package):

**Boolean notWon:** Checks if there are three in a row in any of the three columns and rows or in one of two diagonals. Returns false if someone has won the game.

**Boolean isBlank:** (int int): Get's a position inside my two-dimensional board and checks if that position inhabits a value (-1 or 1) or is empty (0). If it is empty, return true.

**Boolean notFull:** This method checks if the board is completely filled, by going trough every position. If every position is !=0, return false.

---

My problem: I want to make a pre-defined "testBoard" which I fill with custom values in order to create certain game situations. How can I make a testBoard which is applicable for the external function calls? Calling these functions with the testBoard would yield a Boolean-value, which should be applicable for comparison (Assert.assertEquals).

**I somehow get a NullPointerException when I run these Tests, which I do not understand as these Tests should use my pre-defined two dimensional array (testBoard).**

**BoardTest.class**

```
package structurePack;


import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;



public class BoardTest {
    int [][] testBoard;

    /* Schema:
            * (0,0) | (0,1) | (0,2)
            * (1,0) | (1,1) | (1,2)
            * (2,0) | (2,1) | (2,2)
            */


    public int[][]createBoard(){


        testBoard = new int[3][3];
        testBoard[0][0] = 1;
        testBoard[0][1] = -1;
        testBoard[0][2] = 0;
        testBoard[1][0] = 0;
        testBoard[1][1] = 1;
        testBoard[1][2] = 0;
        testBoard[2][0] = 0;
        testBoard[2][1] = -1;
        testBoard[2][2] = 1;
        return testBoard;
    }

    @Test

    public void testNotWon() {
        createBoard();
        Assert.assertEquals(false, Board.notWon());
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotWon2() {
        createBoard();
        Assert.assertEquals(true, Board.notWon());;
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsBlank() {
        createBoard();
        Assert.assertEquals("Spot is not empty", false, Board.isBlank(0,0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsBlank2() {
        createBoard();
        Assert.assertEquals("Spot is empty", true, Board.isBlank(0,2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotFull() {
        createBoard();
        Assert.assertEquals("Board is not completely full", Board.notFull());

    }

    @Test
    public void testNotFull2() {
        createBoard();
        Assert.assertEquals("Board is completely full", false, Board.notFull());

    }
}
```

**Board.class**

```
package structurePack;

/**
 * Created by Yassir on 27.04.2016.
 */

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Board {
    public static int[][] gameBoard;
    public static char[][] consoleGameBoard;
    private static boolean continueGame = true;

    /**
     * This is the constructor for the Board-Class
     */
    public Board() {
        gameBoard = new int[3][3];
        consoleGameBoard = new char[3][3];

        for (int row = 0; row < gameBoard.length; row++) {
            Arrays.fill(gameBoard[row], 0);
        }
    } // end of constructor

    public void displayBoard() {
        for (int row = 0; row < consoleGameBoard.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < consoleGameBoard.length; col++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + consoleGameBoard[row][col]);
                if (col == 0 || col == 1)
                    System.out.print("|");

            }
            System.out.print("\n_________________\n");
        }
    }


    public static boolean updateBoard(int player, int row, int col) {
        if (row >= 0 && row <= 2 && col >= 0 && col <= 2) {
            if (gameBoard[row][col] != 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                gameBoard[row][col] = player;
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void userInput(int player) {
        int row, col;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {

            System.out.printf("Player %s, please enter a row (1-3):", 'O');
            row = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("Player %s, please enter a column (1-3):", 'O');
            col = keyboard.nextInt();

        } while (notValid(row, col));
        updateBoard(player, row - 1, col - 1);
        convertToChar(row - 1, col - 1);
    }

    public static boolean notValid(int row, int col) {
        if (row > 3 || row < 1 || col > 3 || col < 1 || !isBlank(row, col)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean notFull() {
        if (gameBoard[0][0] != 0 && gameBoard[0][1] != 0 && gameBoard[0][2] != 0 && gameBoard[1][0] != 0 && gameBoard[1][1] != 0 && gameBoard[1][2] != 0 &&
                gameBoard[2][0] != 0 && gameBoard[2][1] != 0 && gameBoard[2][2] != 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isBlank(int row, int col) {
        if (gameBoard[row - 1][col - 1] == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println(" -- INVALID! The Position is already taken! --");
            System.out.println(" ------------- Make another Move -------------");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean notWon() {
        // loop over each row and check for winner
        for (int row = 0; row < gameBoard.length; row++) {
            if (gameBoard[row][0] + gameBoard[row][1] +  gameBoard[row][2] == 3 ||gameBoard[row][0] + gameBoard[row][1] +  gameBoard[row][2] == -3) {
                return continueGame = false;
            }
        }
        // loop over each column and check for winner
        for (int col = 0; col < gameBoard[0].length; col++) {
            if (gameBoard[0][col] + gameBoard[1][col] + gameBoard[2][col] == 3 || gameBoard[0][col] + gameBoard[1][col] + gameBoard[2][col] == -3) {
                return continueGame = false;
            }
        }
        // check diagonal 1
        if (gameBoard[0][0] + gameBoard[1][1] + gameBoard[2][2] == 3 || gameBoard[0][0] + gameBoard[1][1] + gameBoard[2][2] == -3) {
            return continueGame = false;
        }
        // check for diagonal 2
        if (gameBoard[2][0] + gameBoard[1][1] + gameBoard[0][2] == 3 ||gameBoard[2][0] + gameBoard[1][1] + gameBoard[0][2] == -3) {
            return continueGame = false;
        } else {
            return continueGame = true;
        }
    }

    public static void convertToChar(int row, int col) {
        char X = 'X';
        char O = 'O';

        if (gameBoard[row][col] == 1) {
            consoleGameBoard[row][col] = X;
        } else {
            consoleGameBoard[row][col] = O;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: why isn't the @Before method useful?

Comment: `createBoard()` would be much more readable with an array literal.

Comment: weird way of writing test. Why would your unit test extend your "structurePack.Board" ?

Comment: and we usually put the unit test at the same package as the System Under Test (SUT)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I've now put the testclass into the respective package.

Comment: It does not make sense after your update: How can `Board.notWon()` know what to check? `Board` is obviously not an object instance, and you are not passing any input (e.g. your `testBoard`) to `notWon()`.  And, a bit off topic, can you make sure your code is properly formatted?

Comment: I guess: **1.** Your `Board` have the 2D array as `static` member  **2.** Your methods in `Board` are all `static`  **3.** You hope your `Board` will use the `testBoard` 2D array you declare in your test auto-magically.  If my guesses above are correct, first thing you need to do is: rewrite your code.  Make `Board` a proper class and make these member fields/methods non-static.

Comment: Hello Adrian Shum, I can't make the methods inside Board non-static as they are called from other classes, for example my MiniMax.class or my Console.class (user input).

Comment: Your update proved my guess is correct.  In short, your code is poorly designed.  Making it non-static doesn't mean that you cannot use it in other class ok?

Comment: Though I can still find a way to test your code, proceeding in such direction is not going to do anything good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you proceed to my solution, read this:

Your code is poorly designed and is inappropriately using `static`.  You should make `Board` "instantiable" and make most, if not all, of your members non-static.  It does not only makes your code more testable, it also is how OOP should look like.

Go back to your problem.  Given that your `Board` methods are accessing your `Board`'s static `gameBoard`, and in your test, you have not set up `Board.gameBoard` (your `createBoard()` is not doing anything meaningful), hence it is giving you NPE when you call those methods.

Just change your `createBoard()` to something like

```
@Before
public void createBoard() {
    Board.gameBoard = new int[][] { {0, 1, 1},
                                    {-1, 0, 1},
                                    {1, 0, -1} };
};

// and remove invocations of `createBoard()` in your test methods
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out a young Padawan :). I will try to improve my coding style!

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
private final Integer[][] testArray = {
        {0, 1, 1},
        {-1, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, -1}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For better learning I would say look for `Data Providers` and their use in `Unit Tests`. You shall get a better approach to test your code.